# Ancestrais em Prolog

Tags: prolog

Olá, preciso criar um predicado que irá retornar todos os ancestrais de uma pessoa. A questão é que só posso passar um parâmetro para essa função.

```
ancestor(Y, X) :- parent(Y, X).
ancestor(X) :- parent(Y, X), ancestor(Y, X).
```

Utilizando dois argumentos no segundo 'ancestor' consigo chegar ao resultado esperado, contudo preciso que seja passado somente um argumento como acima.